# mysql new user write permission refused, read is ok

Tags: mysql

I have mysql server running on 192.168.0.5 and now i have a client PC with adress 192.168.0.50

i created new user for client pc as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'mimi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mimi';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mimi'@'localhost'
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'mimi'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mimi';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mimi'@'%'
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Problem is i can only view(read) the DB on the server. I cant write anything on it.I get the following error Connection refused :connect
Any suggestions?

Comment: it's not a `.` it is `*.*`

Comment: @khuderm the post was misformatted

Comment: How do you try to connect to the database? Show the connection details.

Comment: GRANT ALL ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';

Comment: Be careful with 'ALL', chances are you just need a limited subset of available commands such as CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that solved you issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
    GRANT ALL ON
```

rather than grant all `privileges`

You can verify from the docs too :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Either restart mysql server  by

```
service mysqld restart
```

or flush the privileges by

```
flush privileges
```

Comment: TBH, I wouldn't even suggest a restart here, it's the reason `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` exists.

Comment: Does the mysql service restarts when the pc restarts? If so, then it didnt help